# Trim Event out of Wave in Python

Tags: python-3.x, signal-processing

All,
I am very new to signal processing analysis. Searching google has not led to many results. 
My lead at work gave me bunch of events in waveform. Each event has 30,000 samples. He wants me to do some ML/DL on it.

The problem I am running into is the portion of the waveform that is the actual event is in the middle, with the beginning and end just being noise.

I don't want to crop by # of samples at the beginning and end.

Can someone point me in the right direction to detect the start and end of the actual event 
in Python? Is there a package that does stuff like this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ICA for this problem.. if you want do this in python check this link: [enter link description here](https://cbrnr.github.io/2018/01/29/removing-eog-ica/) Hence, using ICA in eeglab toolbox in matlab is very easier.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qL0z.png)